# httpservletrequest - create new session / change session Id

Tags: java, session, servlets

I'm maintaining a Java web application.

Looking into the login code it gets an HttpSession out of HttpServletRequest via the getSession() method of HttpServletRequest. (It uses some values in the session for authentication purposes)

However I'm worried about session fixation attacks so after I have used the initial session I want to either start a new session or change the session id. Is this possible?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Servlet 3.0 API doesn't allow you to change the session id on an existing session.  Typically, to protect against session fixation, you'll want to just create a new one and invalidate the old one as well.

You can invalidate a session like this

```
request.getSession(false).invalidate();
```

and then create a new session with

`getSession(true)` (`getSession()` should work too)

Obviously, if you have an data in the session that you want to persist, you'll need to copy it from the first session to the second session.

Note, for session fixation protection, it's commonly considered okay to just do this on the authentication request.  But a higher level of security involves a tossing the old session and making a new session for each and every request.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to give a NullPointerException when getSession hasn't been called before?

Comment: True, but I think we're assuming that the session exists.

Comment: I would upvote you if you have used `getSession()` instead of `getSession(boolean)`.

Comment: My question was assuming the session already existed at this point. Thanks for the good answer.

Comment: @BalusC, you would create a session and immediately delete it if it didn't exist before. What for? `request.getSession(false).invalidate();` with a null-check is the correct answer.

Comment: So, this answer presumes you don't have any other important data in the session, correct?  And even the authentication token must be propagated to the new session, correct?

Comment: @chad: Yes, you have to copy all relevant data before invalidating the session, and you can set that data in the new session. If you have some sort of custom auth token, then you also have to copy that.

Answer (score 33):

Since Java EE 7 and Servlet API 3.1 (Tomcat 8) you can use [HttpServletRequest.changeSessionId()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#changeSessionId--) to achieve such behaviour. There is also a listener `HttpSessionIdListener` which will be invoked after each change.

Comment: Shiro and changeSessionId is a powerful combination. It allow me to write my lava logic without distractions 'if(success) request.changeSessionId()' no need to rewrite, I am nere