# Changing a session id of an established session in Jetty 9 server

Tags: servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, httpsession, jetty-9

It is all in the title. Is there a way to do this *after* the session is created, and potentially multiple times during its lifetime? A fallback approach would be to copy all the data from the current session, terminate it, create a new one, and put the data back, but that is not desirable either for a number of reasons.

Use case is related to security - we just need to be able to occasionally change session ids. We are using an embedded Jetty server and have only one "context".

Does anyone have any ideas? If you do, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpServletRequest.changeSessionId()`.
See also this answer: [httpservletrequest - create new session / change session Id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25189604)

Make sure you use the latest jetty version!